# How to test a byte against a hex value?

Tags: c++, char, hex

I want to test if the byte I read from a data file is 0xEE, what should I do? I tried `if (aChar == 0xEE)` but doesn't seems working.

Comment: That is exactly how you test a char, or any other numeric type, against a hexadecimal value. What isn't working? Post some source code.

Comment: What is the type of aChar? Is it a pointer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When reading a signed char, the value will never be 0xEE. IE:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char c = 0xEE;   // assumes your implementation defines char as signed char
    // c is now -18
    if (c == 0xEE)
    {
        printf("Char c is 0xEE");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Char c is NOT 0xEE");
    }

}
```

The output will be

```
Char c is NOT 0xEE
```

When the signed character is read, the value will range from -0x7F to 0x80. An unsigned char is interpreted from 0x00 up to 0xFF, and is typically what you want for "raw" bytes.

Change:

```
char aChar;
```

to

```
unsigned char aChar;
```

and it should work.

Comment: It should be noted that a plain old char can be either signed or unsigned; it's up to the implementation.

Comment: @Martin That's complete semantics. I know you can assign it 0xFF, but the test if a signed char is 0xFF will always fail.

Comment: Just to reiterate James McNellis, it's implementation-dependent whether your example works or not.

Comment: @Doug T: Why will it always fail? If 0xEE isn't representable in a char, then it gets converted to the equivalent negative value anyway, and then it might compare equal to the char.

Comment: @jalf:  If `char` is a signed type, then `char c = 0xEE;` results in `c` being a negative value (-18) and testing `c == 0xEE` will always fail.  Since the hexadecimal integer literal `0xEE` is of type `int`, the `char` will be promoted to `int` for the comparison. `-18 != 238`.

Answer (score 6):

Using a character constant will avoid any implementation defined signed/unsigned character type issues:

```
if( aChar == '\xee' )
```